# SSRS reports displays nothing after deployment

Tags: reporting-services

I have deployed a ssrs report in report server. when I'm trying to run that report in report server, it displays nothing. but it fetches the appropriate result in 'Preview'. I am new to ssrs reports.

My query :

```
if @department is not null and @Course is not null  select
student_name,average from student where student_id=@studentid

else if @department is not null and @Course is null select
student_name,average from student  where student_id=@studentid and
department_name=@department


@department , @course are optional user inputs  
@student_id is mandatory user input
```

Answer (score 0):

try to open the report from the report viewer in the report server, you should get a better message there to what is the problem

Comment: I'm getting this error :

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot impersonate user for data source 'DataSource1'. (rsErrorImpersonatingUser)
This data source is configured to use Windows integrated security. Windows integrated security is either disabled for this report server or your report server is using Trusted Account mode. (rsWindowsIntegratedSecurityDisabled)

Comment: this is a problem with the authentication in the connection string, you are using impersonate or integrated security, try to create an SQL user account on the database server for accessing the report database and change the connection string to start using that account. this should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your SQL Server Reporting Services.